# How to dispose Entity Framework Core in-memory database

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, dependency-injection, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to create clean inmemory database in each unit test. 
When I run multiple tests, data from previous tests remains in the database. How to dispose existing inmemory database?

I initialize each test with following code:

```
 [TestInitialize]
 public void TestInitialize()
 {
     Services = new ServiceCollection();
     Services.AddScoped<DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>>(sp => new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TacsDbContext>()
             .UseInMemoryDatabase("MyTestDbContext")
             .Options);

     Services.AddTransient<InMemoryMyDbContext>();
     Services.AddTransient<MyDbContext>(sp => sp.GetService<InMemoryTacsDbContext>());

    ServiceProvider = Services.BuildServiceProvider();
 }

 [TestMethod]
 public void Test1()
 {
     using (var dbContext = ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>()) ...
 }

 [TestMethod]
 public void Test2()
 {
     using (var dbContext = ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>()) ...
 }
```

I use .NET Core 2.0, and Entity Framework Core 2.0

**EDIT**
I wasn't  able to use the standard registration: `Services.AddDbContext<InMemoryMyDbContext>(...)`, because

```
public class InMemoryMyDbContext : MyDbContext
{
    public InMemoryMyDbContext(DbContextOptions<InMemoryMyDbContext> options)
      : base(options) { }  //compiler error

    public InMemoryMyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
      : base(options) { }  //runtime IoC error
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
      : base(options) { } 
}
```

Comment: Do you really need all the DI wrapping? why not just call ``new MyDbContext`` in your test function.

Comment: I actually do. My tests are more complex and I use this approach in integration tests. Besides, I use IoC as  [auto mocking container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the solution in my case was to call **DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseApplicationServiceProvider()**

```
Services.AddScoped<DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>>(sp => new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
        .UseApplicationServiceProvider(sp)
        .UseInMemoryDatabase("Test")
        .Options);
```

This method is called automatically when you setup ServiceCollection the usuall way, so in following case the database is created from scratch each time

```
Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("Test"));
```

At the end, I was able to modify MyDbContext so that I call the line above:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected MyDbContext (DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public MyDbContext (DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) 
       : this((DbContextOptions)options) { }
}

public class InMemoryMyDbContext : MyDbContext
{
    public InMemoryMyDbContext (DbContextOptions<InMemoryTacsDbContext> options) 
        : base(options) { } 
}

Services.AddDbContext<InMemoryMyDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("Test"), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
Services.AddTransient<MyDbContext>(sp => sp.GetService<InMemoryMyDbContext>());
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Nuget package **Effort**

It is a simple and fast in-memory database ideal for unit-testing

You can start it with an empty database; if desired fill it using a database seeder, or fill it with values from a test CSV file.

See [Tutorials Effort - Entity Framework Unit Testing Tool](https://effort.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tutorials)

Your DbContext probably will look similar to:

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base() { } // constructor using config file
    public BloggingContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : 
        base(nameOrConnectionString) { }

    public DbSet<...> ...{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<...> ...{ get; set; }
}
```

Just add one constructor and you can use your in-memory database as if it was your original database:

```
 public MyDbContext(DbConnection connection) : base(connection, true) { }
```

You pass the DbConnection to the test database, this connection is passed to the DbContext class. The true parameter says that when the DbContext is disposed, that the DbConnection should also be Disposed.

Usage would be:

```
[TestMethod]
public void UnitTest_X()
{
    var dbConnection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(dbConnection)
    {
        // perform your test of MyDbContext as if it was connected to your
        // original database
    }
}
```

A simple copy-paste code example for a console program with an Effort database that uses a one-to-many relationship can be found [here on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770204/writing-unit-test-using-ef6-entity-framework-6/46771085#46771085)

Comment: What are the advantages over built-in entity framework in-memory provider?

Comment: If you want to are using entity framework, as the asker is, and you want to unit test your code, you don't want to unit test databases, nor entity framework. Your code should work with anything that works with entity framework. An in-memory database is faster to set-up, and instantly cleaned, so previous tests can't influence your current tests.

Comment: I agree, but entity framework core has in-memory database out if the box. Why would I use effort, since it does the same?

Comment: Well, probably because I didn't know about its existence. A few years ago I needed an in-memory database, and stackoverflow suggested using Effort. Apparently since then, Entity Framework expanded with an in-memory DbContext

Comment: Effort does not support EntityFramework Core. It only supports EntityFramework